# Kotlin: Filtering a list return the original list if no match found

Tags: kotlin

I want an inline function that filters through a list and returns the original list if there is no match rather than returning null

I have this feature that filters through the list and returns the filtered list or empty

```
fun List<Obj>?.filterQueryText(queryText : String?) = this?.filter {
    queryText.equals(it.objName)
}.orEmpty()
```

How do I make it so that it will return to the original list if no match is found in the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
fun List<Obj>?.filterQueryText(queryText : String?) = this?.filter {
    queryText.equals(it.objName)
}?.run {if (isEmpty()) this@filterQueryText else this}.orEmpty()
```

see it in action [here](https://pl.kotl.in/Q2fW8KVzQ)

Comment: I spent almost an hour learning about scope functions and almost achieved it with `apply` and `with`but the `this@filterQueryText` was the interesting part, I could not understand how you could explicitly refer to the object reference of the outside method. `with(Object)` cannot work in this case because there is a nullable type involved. I have added my approach with `apply` just in case

Comment: @gtxtreme i rejected your edit. hijacking my answer to add your approach is not the right way to do it. If you want people to know your answer you should post your own answer

Comment: I meant no offence in any way Ivo, but I thought that adding the answer as an edit would make more sense since it is not very different from what you've posted. I will add my answer as a comment in anyway

Comment: https://pl.kotl.in/gvsnQlr8B

Here's my approach using `apply`

Answer (score 4):

Generic filter for `List<T>`:

```kotlin
fun <T> List<T>?.filterOrOriginal(predicate: (T) -> Boolean) : List<T>? =
    this?.filter(predicate).takeUnless { it.isNullOrEmpty() } ?: this
```

Specific filter for `List<Obj>`:

```
fun List<Obj>?.filterQueryTextOrOriginal(queryText : String?) : List<Obj>? =
    this?.filterOrOriginal { queryText == it.objName }
```